# Fatal error: Class 'Front' not found

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

try to access my site showing this error.
Fatal error: Class 'Front' not found in /home/ezaboon/public_html/system/framework.php on line 93

Comment: What are u even trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed. am uninstall vqmod.